# New Note quick action not appearing in lightning page

Tags: lightning, leads, quickaction

I have created one quick action on a lead object, which creates notes records.
I also added that note quick action to the page layout but it's not getting displayed on the page.

I tried to do the same in my developer org and there I can see the quick action.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: do you have any record types?

Comment: No, I don't have any record types